# C# object vs. object? (nullable object)

Tags: c#, object, nullable

Short question - what is difference between **object** and **object?** (nullable object)?

I know what nullable types are and for example with numbers it makes perfect sense, but what is the point of nullable object, when object by itself can be null. Am I missing something?

Story behind. I had project in Core 5.0 and 3.1, both had background tasks and based on Microsoft doc, I had function with object parameter like this:

```
private void DoWork(object state)
{
   //some code
}
```

[Example from Microsoft documentation - Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks-1)

But in Core 6.0 there are some changes and now it looks like this:

```
private void DoWork(object? state)
{
   //some code
}
```

[Example from Microsoft documentation - Core 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks)

Which now triggers Warning CS8632: The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context.

It is not much of a issue, but more like a curiosity.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're essentially asking "what is the point of nullable reference types?"

Comment: This is a new feature called [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). There is little overlap with `Nullable` for value types, although it uses the same syntax.

Comment: NullReferenceException is something that has cost billions. This is a method of forcing the software developer to reduce this problem by explicitly marking an reference type to be able to contain a null value. The compiler can also get more insight into which reference is able to contain a null value and point this out to the developer.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I am dum dum, if only I would read that warning more carefully, then google would not always showing me this link [nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types) and I would find that doc page You sent. Now it is obvious. Thanks a lot guys. If You post it as answer, I will mark it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: T? is syntax sugar for the `Nullable<T>`

Microsoft added  this pattern in .Net Core 6 for all owned libraries, so you can doing this.
**I'ts** just to warn you that there may be null in here.

when you add `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` tag to project file, enable this ability of compiler.